# Get Javascript value with Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to get these JavaScript values from web application.

```
var demoPlayResponse = {
 "winningPrizeIndex" : 1,
 "playMode"          : "NORMAL",
 "customerId"        : "pli",
 "gameVersion"       : "0-1-86",
 "gameId"            : "blue250k",
 "seed"              : 99
};
mws.GameModel.setPlayResponse(demoPlayResponse);
mws.GameModel.setGameMode(demoPlayResponse.playMode);
```

When I start the game I use Chrome development tools and I insert manually this code.

How I can get the values from Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript code like this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(script);
```

For your use case, I would recommend making a function getDemoPlayResponse() that returns your variable and calling that function from Java class like this.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return getDemoPlayResponse()");
```

Comment: I can't make code modifications. How I can access the values from the mws JavaScript Object?

Comment: Try returning the object ("return mws.GameModel") for example